$q$-potential in grand canonical ensemble
I was recently going through R.K. Pathria's Grand canonical ensemble chapter and found the following section confusing under physical significance of statistical quantities. The author mentions;

To establish a link between the Grand canonical ensemble and thermodynamics, we
introduce a quantity , called  potential as follows:
$$ = {∑_{r,s}xp(−_−_)}$$
 is a function of ,  and all the energy states .

To give a brief overview of the expression, here, $$∑_{r,s}xp(−_−_)$$ is the grand partition function.
And in the ensemble, there are, $$n_{r,s}$$ systems with energy $$E_s$$ and number of particles $$N_r,$$ and hence the summation inside the logarithm is over all the systems in the ensemble.
The restrictive conditions for Grand canonical ensemble are,
$$∑_{s,r} _{,} = ℕ
$$$$
∑_{s,r}_{,}_ = ℕ <  >$$ and
$$∑_{s,r}_{,}_ = ℕ <  >$$
My question is, why is q not a function of Nr while for grand canonical ensemble, the number of particles is also a variable? The only reason I can think of is that somehow due to restrictive conditions of the grand canonical ensemble, Nr does not remain an independent variable i.e. it's somehow dependent on other 3 parameters but I can't understand how.

It is not totally clear from what you have said exactly what is meant by $\mathbf{E_s}$. If it is the set off allowed energies for the system, then the corresponding set of allowed values for $\mathbf{N_s}$ is just the natural numbers, so it is not really worth mentioning. If $\mathbf{E_s}$ is the set of configurations of the system (each of which has some energy) then each configuration of the system also has some particle number, so there is no separate set of particle number states

@BySymmetry I apologize for the confusion. As you've rightly mentioned, it's the former. Say for any system in the ensemble labeled $$n_{20,3}$$, the system has 20 particles and the energy is E3 viz. one of the allowed values of energy  for the system. The system can however freely exchange energy and particles with  other systems in the ensemble.

TL;DR There is an assumed implicit volume dependence in the energies.
The grand canonical partition function, with the sum is carried out over all microstates symbolically labeled by $r,s$. is $$\mathcal{Q}(\alpha,\beta,V) = \sum_{r,s} e^{-\alpha N_r - \beta E_s}$$
$\mathcal{Q}(\alpha,\beta,V)$ can depend only on the arguments stated, so this must be valid for the so-called $q$-potential defined by Pathria
$$ q = \ln (\alpha, \beta, V) = \ln \sum_{r,s} e^{-\alpha N_r - \beta E_s}$$
However, while it is explicitly visible where the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are located, it is not directly clear how the $q$-potential depends on volume. We can now assume that this information is hidden in the energy eigenvalues $E_s$ of the system we are examining, and for simplicity we can assume that the number of particles $N_r$ has nothing to do with volume (though we could generalize to that case as well)
Now to write the complete differential of $q(\alpha,\beta, V)$
$$dq = \left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial \alpha}\right)_{\beta, V} d\alpha + \left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial \beta}\right)_{\alpha, V} d\beta + \left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial V}\right)_{\alpha, \beta} dV$$
we can use $q = \ln \sum_{r,s} e^{-\alpha N_r - \beta E_s}$ to write
$$dq = - \overline{N} d\alpha - \overline{E} d\beta - \frac{\beta}{\mathcal N}\sum_{r,s}\langle n_{r,s}\rangle \left(\frac{\partial E_s}{\partial V}\right)_{\alpha,\beta} dV\,,$$ where equations (4.2.5 - 4.2.7) were used. In Pathria, this last piece is left implicit as $\frac{\beta}{\mathcal N}\sum_{r,s}\langle n_{r,s}\rangle dE_s$.
We can now follow Pathria in identifying thermodynamic quantities by writing
$$d(q +\overline{N} \alpha + \overline{E} \beta)= \alpha d \overline{N}  + \beta d \overline{E} - \frac{\beta}{\mathcal N}\sum_{r,s}\langle n_{r,s}\rangle \left(\frac{\partial E_s}{\partial V}\right)_{\alpha,\beta} dV$$
Now, if we compare this with ($k$ included for dimensional reasons) $$kTdS = k(dU + \delta W - \mu d \overline{N})$$ the identifications follow:
\begin{align}
&\delta W = - \frac{\beta}{\mathcal N}\sum_{r,s}\langle n_{r,s}\rangle \left(\frac{\partial E_s}{\partial V}\right)_{\alpha,\beta} dV\\
&q +\overline{N} \alpha + \overline{E} \beta = S/k\\
&\alpha = -\beta \mu\\
&\beta = 1/kT
\end{align}
